# Sort series of label elements by their "title" attribute according to list of values

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, label, title

I have a series of label elements that I want to sort by their "title" attribute according to a specific list of values (array).

I am trying to have them sorted starting by their place on the color wheel, and doing a sort based on a hex code regex doesn't work because there are a couple values that through the color progression off.

The list of values in the "labelTitles " array is order in which I want them to appear ... it just isn't working for me though.

```
<fieldset class="radio-table">
<legend>Color</legend>
    <label class="color-00C200" title="00C200" for="rad-00C200"> <input type="radio" value="00C200" id="rad-00C200"></label>
    <label class="color-F3F300" title="F3F300" for="rad-F3F300"> <input type="radio" value="F3F300" id="rad-F3F300"></label>
    <label class="color-6C09A2" title="6C09A2" for="rad-6C09A2"> <input type="radio" value="6C09A2" id="rad-6C09A2"></label>
    <label class="color-62D800" title="62D800" for="rad-62D800"> <input type="radio" value="62D800" id="rad-62D800"></label>
    <label class="color-F36E00" title="F36E00" for="rad-F36E00"> <input type="radio" value="F36E00" id="rad-F36E00"></label>
    <label class="color-F3DD00" title="F3DD00" for="rad-F3DD00"> <input type="radio" value="F3DD00" id="rad-F3DD00"></label>
    <label class="color-F3A200" title="F3A200" for="rad-F3A200"> <input type="radio" value="F3A200" id="rad-F3A200"></label>
    <label class="color-C3006E" title="C3006E" for="rad-C3006E"> <input type="radio" value="C3006E" id="rad-C3006E"></label>
    <label class="color-F3C900" title="F3C900" for="rad-F3C900"> <input type="radio" value="F3C900" id="rad-F3C900"></label>
    <label class="color-9E009E" title="9E009E" for="rad-9E009E"> <input type="radio" value="9E009E" id="rad-9E009E"></label>
    <label class="color-4F0EA5" title="4F0EA5" for="rad-4F0EA5"> <input type="radio" value="4F0EA5" id="rad-4F0EA5"></label>
    <label class="color-F3B600" title="F3B600" for="rad-F3B600"> <input type="radio" value="F3B600" id="rad-F3B600"></label>
    <label class="color-F38B00" title="F38B00" for="rad-F38B00"> <input type="radio" value="F38B00" id="rad-F38B00"></label>
    <label class="color-009292" title="009292" for="rad-009292"> <input type="radio" value="009292" id="rad-009292"></label>
    <label class="color-D90042" title="D90042" for="rad-D90042"> <input type="radio" value="D90042" id="rad-D90042"></label>
    <label class="color-C2EB00" title="C2EB00" for="rad-C2EB00"> <input type="radio" value="C2EB00" id="rad-C2EB00"></label>
    <label class="color-F30000" title="F30000" for="rad-F30000"> <input type="radio" value="F30000" id="rad-F30000"></label>
    <label class="color-3613A7" title="3613A7" for="rad-3613A7"> <input type="radio" value="3613A7" id="rad-3613A7"></label>
    <label class="color-00A75F" title="00A75F" for="rad-00A75F"> <input type="radio" value="00A75F" id="rad-00A75F"></label>
    <label class="color-0A5D9C" title="0A5D9C" for="rad-0A5D9C"> <input type="radio" value="0A5D9C" id="rad-0A5D9C"></label>
    <label class="color-97E300" title="97E300" for="rad-97E300"> <input type="radio" value="97E300" id="rad-97E300"></label>
    <label class="color-F34500" title="F34500" for="rad-F34500"> <input type="radio" value="F34500" id="rad-F34500"></label>
    <label class="color-113DA3" title="113DA3" for="rad-113DA3"> <input type="radio" value="113DA3" id="rad-113DA3"></label>
    <label class="color-1A1AAA" title="1A1AAA" for="rad-1A1AAA"> <input type="radio" value="1A1AAA" id="rad-1A1AAA"></label>
```

This is my current function which is not working.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Sort the lables by title
        function sortByTitle() {
            var labelTitles = ['F30000', 'F34500', 'F36E00', 'F38B00', 'F3A200', 'F3B600', 'F3C900', 'F3DD00', 'F3F300', 'C2EB00', '97E300', '62D800', '00C200', '00A75F', '009292', '0A5D9C', '113DA3', '1A1AAA', '3613A7', '4F0EA5', '6C09A2', '9E009E', 'C3006E', 'D90042'];
            var fieldsetOfLabels = $('.radio-table');
            var listLabels = fieldsetOfLabels.children('label').get();

            listLabels.sort(function (a, b) {
                var compA = $.inArray($(a).find('label[title]').text(), labelTitles);
                var compB = $.inArray($(b).find('label[title]').text(), labelTitles);
            });
            $(fieldsetOfLabels).append(listItems);
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs some changes:

- Call the `sortByTitle` function.
- Use the `attr` method to get the title (as Blazemonger already mentioned)
- Compare the labels and return the result in the sort callback.
- Use the `listLabels` variable to append items, not `listItems`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NFp7Z/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function sortByTitle() {
    var labelTitles = ['F30000', 'F34500', 'F36E00', 'F38B00', 'F3A200', 'F3B600', 'F3C900', 'F3DD00', 'F3F300', 'C2EB00', '97E300', '62D800', '00C200', '00A75F', '009292', '0A5D9C', '113DA3', '1A1AAA', '3613A7', '4F0EA5', '6C09A2', '9E009E', 'C3006E', 'D90042'];
    var fieldsetOfLabels = $('.radio-table');
    var listLabels = fieldsetOfLabels.children('label').get();

    listLabels.sort(function(a, b) {
        var compA = $.inArray($(a).attr('title'), labelTitles);
        var compB = $.inArray($(b).attr('title'), labelTitles);
        return compA < compB ? -1 : 1;
    });
    $(fieldsetOfLabels).append(listLabels);
  }

  sortByTitle();

});
```

Comment: This code works, but is duplicating each label when I implement it in my project.  I added the colors to the fiddle you created: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/NFp7Z/2/

Comment: The labels and radio buttons are being dynamically generated by a loop using .NET Razor syntax.  Is that a factor in why it is doubling the labels?

Comment: @thedigitalman: It's hard to say why the labels would be duplicated without seeing the code. If the generated HTML code looks like the example, then it doesn't matter how it is created. When it reaches the browser, there is no difference between static content and content created dynamically on the server.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had two forms on the same page (Add and Edit).  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$(a).find('label[title]').text()
```

try

```
$(a).attr('title')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var b= $('.radio-table label');

b.sort(function(a, b)
    {
        if ($(a).prop("title") == $(b).prop("title")) { return 0; }
        if ($(a).prop("title") > $(b).prop("title"))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

Keep simple.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/paulodiogo/7WyFD/2/)